# Redis stringified array VS array of stringified structs

Tags: go, struct, redis

I need to use redis in golang as cache and store a array of structs in it. Since redis allows only storing array of strings(correct me if I'm wrong), I'll marshal the items in my array. Was wondering shall I use redis list where I'm storing marshaled structs in string format OR I can just marshal the whole array and store as key<>value in redis and not use list. 
One pro of using list is I can fetch ranged items from the list but scale is not the problem here since I'll be storing less than 100 items in the list. What else should I consider here.

Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends of how you want to use redis

For instance, store one struct using json (or any kind of serialization) and store it in a single position is easy to read / write.

But if you need to efficiently retrieve/ update one field, you can save it in a different way. However this scenario is pretty rare and complex to handle.

For instance you need to be sure you write always in the same order, to calculate the right offset. If you need to add a new field, will be really difficult to be 100% backward compatible. You probably need to create a new type (like a version 2).

Comment: Understood. Ordering is not important for me because eviction logic is custom so I'll have to retrieve the whole list.